# Неразрешенный внешний символ при линковке библиотеки boringssl

Tags: visual-c++, rust, static, library

Я пытаюсь скомпилировать свою библиотек-оболочку для boringssl.
Я скомпилировал файл crypto.lib, который определенно содержит символ AES_set_encrypt_key, судя по команде

```
nm crypto.lib --demangle
```

Затем я сгенерировал ffi файл, который определяет этот символ следующим образом:

```
use std::os::raw::{c_void, c_char, c_int, c_uchar, c_uint}; 

#[repr(C)] 
pub struct aes_key_st { 
    pub rd_key: [u32; 60usize], 
    pub rounds: c_uint, 
}

pub type AES_KEY = aes_key_st; 

extern "C" {
    pub fn AES_set_encrypt_key(key: *const u8, bits:c_uint, aeskey: *mut AES_KEY) -> c_int; pub fn foo() -> c_int; 
}
```

И здесь оригинальный:

```
...
struct aes_key_st {
  uint32_t rd_key[4 * (AES_MAXNR + 1)];
  unsigned rounds;
};

typedef struct aes_key_st AES_KEY;

OPENSSL_EXPORT int AES_set_encrypt_key(const uint8_t *key, unsigned bits, AES_KEY *aeskey);
...
```

build.rs:

```
fn main() {
    let out_dir = "<path_to_lib>"
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", out_dir);
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=crypto");
}
```

Но, к сожалению, я получаю ошибку LNK2019 (неразрешенный внешний символ) при компиляции этого кода.

Из-за чего может возникать такая ошибка?

Comment: Что это за объявление функции там в конце длинной строки: `pub fn foo() -> c_int;`? Оно там намеренно?